# Is there a "Total Bitcoin Days" metric?

Tags: charts, bitcoin-days-destroyed

Recently people have been talking about Bitcoin Days Destroyed. I am curious, is there a place I can find out something like Total Bitcoin Days: the number of days since each bitcoin has moved, all added together?

EDIT:

I am aware of Bitcoin Days Destroyed, and what they are (at least, I am pretty sure I am), I am looking for a metric that shows the opposite of Bitcoin Days Destroyed; maybe better wording would be "Bitcoin Days Not Destroyed". Perhaps my wording is off. Please suggest how I can clairify if so.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are viewing the metric incorrectly. The notion of [Bitcoin Days Destroyed](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Bitcoin_Days_Destroyed) is not relative to any other standard of measure. Rather, it is *the* standard of measure.

To clarify, there is no "gold standard" for Bitcoin Days Destroyed saying "*if all Bitcoins had been spent within X weeks the total would be Y*". That just doesn't make any sense. Think about it like this: how would one calculate what the DOW would be at today, had it not fallen 200 points? One wouldn't! It cannot be done; the points are there only to show the relationship of the market from day-to-day, month-to-month, or *n*-to-*n*. They have no standard to which they are measured.

Answer (score 0):

https://blockchain.info/charts/bitcoin-days-destroyed?timespan=1year&showDataPoints=false&daysAverageString=1&show_header=true&scale=0&address= is most likely what you are looking for.

You may also want to take a look at this https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Bitcoin_Days_Destroyed if want to learn more.

I don't know if you can find any place online that has total bitcoin days destroyed but I am sure someone will prove me wrong.

**Edit:**

I also found this old post that gives a great explanation [What are "bitcoin days destroyed"?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/845/what-are-bitcoin-days-destroyed)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to measure the number of days since spent.  So you can total the number of days since last spent for every UTXO, and here you can choose to only include UTXOs that are not spent today, which would be "bitcoin days not destroyed", or include all UTXOs that made it to today (regardless of whether it is spent today), which would be more like "total bitcoin days".  Then you could look at the fraction of the latter that are "destroyed".